# Get rid of "Invite to Messenger" forever

Tags: facebook-messenger, ads

Facebook Messenger displays a huge banner nagging me into sending unsolicited advertisement:

[image: Invite to Messenger - XYZ will get a link to install the app.]

It is a serious drawback of the app because:

- It wastes a lot of screen estate
- It capture the eye's attention, making me less productive
- Sending it would be very creepy in the first place
- The banner is very easy to tap by mistake, it is huge and there is no confirmation
- Clicking the X is not a solution as I would need to do it for thousands of people.

Is there a kind of setting or add-on that removes or at least hides these banners or makes them less easy to tap by mistake? Apparently it is possible on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I doubt you can get rid of it because Facebook wants people to use their messaging platform.

I would try third party Facebook apps such as Face Slim, Tinfoil for Facebook, etc...  Don't trust them all however and do your research into the permissions they use.  I'd consider anything on F-Droid to be safe.  Or use your browser instead of an app to check it.

Of course you could also just delete Facebook.

Comment: I wonder how the add-on is made on iOS, though.